# How to implement a private chat like the facebook one using node.js and socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

Here is the code I have written but it can't chat with logged in users
**Server side**

```
var usernames = {};

// rooms which are currently available in chat
var rooms = [];

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('USER_ONLINE', function (data) {
        rooms.push(data);
    });

    // when the client emits 'adduser', this listens and executes
    socket.on('adduser', function (username) {
        // store the username in the socket session for this client
        socket.username = username;
        // store the room name in the socket session for this client
        socket.room = 'room1';
        // add the client's username to the global list
        usernames[username] = username;
        // send client to room 1
        socket.join('room1');
        // echo to client they've connected
        socket.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', 'you have connected to room');
        // echo to room 1 that a person has connected to their room
        socket.broadcast.to('room1').emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', username + ' has connected to this room');
        socket.emit('updaterooms', rooms, 'room1');
    });

    // when the client emits 'sendchat', this listens and executes
    socket.on('sendchat', function (rum,data) {
        // we tell the client to execute 'updatechat' with 2 parameters
        io.sockets.in(socket.room).emit('updatechat', socket.username, data,rum);
    });

    socket.on('switchRoom', function (newroom) {
        socket.leave(socket.room);
        socket.join(newroom);
        socket.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', 'you have connected to '+ newroom);
        // sent message to OLD room
        socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', socket.username+' has left this room');
        // update socket session room title
        socket.room = newroom;
        socket.broadcast.to(newroom).emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', socket.username+' has joined this room');
        socket.emit('updaterooms', rooms, newroom);
    });


    // when the user disconnects.. perform this
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        // remove the username from global usernames list
        delete usernames[socket.username];
        // update list of users in chat, client-side
        io.sockets.emit('updateusers', usernames);
        // echo globally that this client has left
        socket.broadcast.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', socket.username + ' has disconnected');
        socket.leave(socket.room);
    });
});
```

**Client SIde**

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8585');

socket.on('connect', function () {
    // call the server-side function 'adduser' and send one parameter (value of prompt)
    socket.emit('adduser', '<?php  echo $usermanager_user_company[0]['pc_users']['us_username'];?>');
});

$('#chatmsg').each(function () {
    var list = $(this).find('li span').html();
    socket.emit('USER_ONLINE',list);
});
socket.on('updatechat', function (username, data,rum) {
    $('.'+rum).append('<li><b>'+username + ':</b> ' + data + '</li>');
});
socket.on('updaterooms', function (rooms, current_room) {

    socket.emit('switchRoom', current_room);
});
function switchRoom (room) {
    //alert(room);

    active(room);
}
function active(room) {
    //var message2 = $('.'+room).val();
    //socket.emit('sendchat', room,message2);

    $('.'+room).keydown(function (event) {
        if(event.keyCode == 13) {
            var message2=$(this).val();
            //  alert('Hi');
            // tell server to execute 'sendchat' and send along one parameter
            socket.emit('sendchat',room, message2);
            //$('.messages li').last().focus();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi. At stackoverflow we help people with specific problems. I'm afraid that simply posting code and saying that it isn't working is not enough for people to help you easily. Please specify what you are having trouble with.

Comment: Thanks,I can chat with multiple users by group.but  when different users login with their account so these user can conversation both.not as public group

Comment: You can have both clients join a uniquely named room where messages will only be exchanged between them (and they could in theory optionally invite other people). Or exchange messages server side between two cached sockets that you can identify.